# local edge-connectivity

Tags: graph-theory

For every positive integer $n$ construct a graph G on $n$ vertices in which
the number of different local edge-connectivity values is
at least $n-1$. I know that for a complete graph $K_n), \lambda(K_n)=n-1$, my problem is how to construct graphs whose different local edge-connectivity

---

is at least $n-1$. Can we use $K_n$ to construct this kind of graph or do we have other means to generalize it? Thanks for your cooperation.

Comment: I think you misunderstand the question. It's not that you want $\lambda(G)$ to be at least $n-1$ (for which, yes, $K_n$ would do); it's that, among all the values $\lambda_G(u,v)$ where $u,v$ are different vertices, you want to get at least $n-1$ different ones.

Comment: @MishaLavrov, you are right that is what i can't come across and need some hint how I can proceed, thanks